# Laravel Validations where one filed is unique where other filed must have some id

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass `$params['user_id']` to $fieldValidations and check if the hour is unique for specific `user_id` not for all hours `hour` in the database table

I created a model post

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'hour'];
    public static $fieldValidations = [
        'user_id'  => 'required',
        'hour'      => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|unique:post,hour,NULL,user_id,'
    ];
}
```

and a controller post

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $params = $request->all();
        $params['user_id'] = 12;  

        $validator = Validator::make($params, Post::$fieldValidations);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::json($validator->errors()->all(), 422);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using the unique validation rule. From Laravel 5.7 documentation:

```
The field under validation must be unique in a given database table.
```

Note it says table and not column.

You may have to just query the database and return a JSON response error if it fails. Also, in your current code inside the validation rules, you are specifying that user_id is the primary id key column in the post table. I think that is likely an error and should be removed, even though it's irrelevant given that you can't accomplish what you want using the unique rule. Also, you ended the rule with a comma.

```
if (Post::where(['user_id' => $params['user_id'], 'hour' => $params['hour']])->exists()) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Error', 'errors' => ['hour_error' => ['That hour already exists on the user!']]], 422);
}
```

Lastly, instead of using `$params = $request->all()`, I prefer to use the `request()` helper function and just inline it into the rest of the code. But, that's up to you.